# I have two titles in the same row but I don't know how to layout the page to make it work on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, layout

```
<div class="row rowItem">

<div class="labelTitle col-sm-3">
    <h2>Section Title</h2>
</div>


<div class="labelTitle col-sm-offset-6">
    <h2>Section Title</h2>
</div>


<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="image">
        <a href="#">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/367x245" title=""></a>
    </div> 

    <div class="text">
        <h4 class="font-bold">
            <a href="#">Title</a></h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus pretium tempus dolor, non consequat massa semper in. Donec consectetur blandit urna, eu dictum ipsum rutrum vitae.</p> 
    </div> 
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="image">
        <a href="#">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/367x245" title=""></a>
    </div> 

    <div class="text">
        <h4 class="font-bold">
            <a href="#">Title</a></h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus pretium tempus dolor, non consequat massa semper in. Donec consectetur blandit urna, eu dictum ipsum rutrum vitae.</p> 
    </div> 
</div>


<div class="col-sm-3">

    <div class="image">
        <a href="#">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/367x245" title=""></a>
    </div> 

    <div class="text">
        <h4 class="font-bold">
            <a href="#">Title</a></h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus pretium tempus dolor, non consequat massa semper in. Donec consectetur blandit urna, eu dictum ipsum rutrum vitae.</p> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

You can find the example here http://diegopalma.com/test/

The last row has 3 columns. The fist two columns belong to one section title and the third column has another section title.

I manage to display it correctly on Desktop using the offset class for the second title but of course my approach doesn't work for mobile.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Whats preventing you from putting the last section in its own row so it will have its own section title?

Comment: The issue is from however your "responsive" layout is functioning, it's just bubbling the section headers up rather than treating the sections as blocks, with each substory as a block as well. IE: It's trying to be smarter than it is. I can almost guarantee this problem will vanish if you stick to one section heading per row, and tbh, that would improve desktop layout as well.

Comment: @crazymatt you are right... that's what I need to do. I'm a beginner and I haven't got use to nest rows inside rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <h2>Section Title</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                <div class="image">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/367x245" class="img-responsive col-xs-12" style="padding:0;" title="">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div><!--/.col-->
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                <div class="image">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/367x245" class="img-responsive col-xs-12" style="padding:0;" title="">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div><!--/.col-->
        </div><!--/.row-->
    </div><!--/.col-->

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <h2>Section Title</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                <div class="image">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/367x245" class="img-responsive col-xs-12" style="padding:0;" title="">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div><!--/.col-->
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                <div class="image">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/367x245" class="img-responsive col-xs-12" style="padding:0;" title="">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div><!--/.col-->
        </div><!--/.row-->
    </div><!--/.col-->
</div><!--/.row-->
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you so much.

I got confused with nesting a row inside another row.

Comment: It can get pretty confusing when it comes to nesting with bootstrap. Glad this worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create some custom css to handle that or nest your containers.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>Section Title</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="image">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/367x245" title="">
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="text">
                    <h4 class="font-bold">
                        <a href="#">Title</a>
                    </h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus pretium tempus dolor, non consequat massa semper in. Donec consectetur blandit urna, eu dictum ipsum rutrum vitae.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="image">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/367x245" title="">
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="text">
                    <h4 class="font-bold">
                        <a href="#">Title</a>
                    </h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus pretium tempus dolor, non consequat massa semper in. Donec consectetur blandit urna, eu dictum ipsum rutrum vitae.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>Section Title</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">

                <div class="image">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/367x245" title="">
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="text">
                    <h4 class="font-bold">
                        <a href="#">Title</a>
                    </h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus pretium tempus dolor, non consequat massa semper in. Donec consectetur blandit urna, eu dictum ipsum rutrum vitae.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```